# Dynamically add a placeholder in a textbox in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, placeholder, ssrs-2008-r2, tag-cloud

Is there a way to dynamically add a placeholder in a textbox in SSRS?

What I'm trying to do is to have a placeholders as much as the data i have in a  certain field. for example, I have a total of 20 data in this certain field, then I also want to have 20 placeholders to hold each of the data.

Currently, I am working on a Tag cloud. what I'm doing right now is, I am concatenating every data and put it in a single textbox (a single placeholder as well), what I want to do is to have a different place placeholders for each of the data so I can have a drill through action in each of the data.

Comment: I don't think the way you are trying to do it is very easy.  I'd try looking at this: http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/jeoc/archive/2013/09/06/word-cloud-reports.aspx

Comment: That is what I currently have right now. The texts are concatenated to produce a one single HTML string. in this case, I will only have 1 ID for all the words as a whole, which will not allow me to have a drillthrough action per word.

in Visual studio, there is a way to dynamically add objects like textboxes and labels. I was just thinking that maybe there is way to do that in placeholders in SSRS?

Comment: Why couldn't you compose your html string to include the anchor tags that take you to the drill-through report?